# Old anime: main character can slow down time and move really fast

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

It’s an old anime, maybe from the 80s. From what I remember, the main character had some operation and afterwards he could push a button on his neck and slow down time for himself and move really fast. He gets recruited into this team that has super powers and the leader is a really smart baby, they also wear red and each member is assigned a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds a lot like the anime [*Cyborg 009*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_009). Since the manga is very popular in Japan, it spawned a lot of anime series (one of which was created at the end of the 70s).
Your points:

- There is 001, who is a newborn baby with psychic powers and a super-human intelligence (but he's not the leader, rather he's the only one that can perceive the plans of the enemies, because of his ESP powers)
- The protagonist can move very fast (but I don't remember the button on the neck... maybe it was created in one of the many reboots)
- They are a team of cyborgs (each one with a specific power), and dress red with white scarves
- Every one has a number as identification (from 001 up to the protagonist, who is 009)

Comment: The on button is in 009's mouth; one of his teeth IIRC.